# Installing XML-RPC on Mamp Pro

Tags: php, mamp, xml-rpc, mamp-pro

I've been trying to install XML-RPC on Mamp Pro OSX version with no success. Does anyone have experience of being able to get this to work who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what are the problems you faced?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, i tried a number of different things to try and get the extension but I couldn't get hold or generate the .so file required to enable xml-rpc.